# The use of subjunctive in prayer

Tags: tense, subjunctives

1. We pray God give you health.
2. We pray God gives you health.
3. We pray God shall give you health.
4. We pray God may give you health.

Is the 1st one (the subjunctive) ok? Do we necessarily place a modal after the word God working as the subject?

And what about this:

> We pray to God that he give you health.

Comment: Of the 4 numbered options you listed, *only* the first is standard (see this Ngrams result: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+pray+God+give%2Cwe+pray+God+gives%2Cwe+pray+God+shall+give%2Cwe+pray+God+may+give&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Your final sentence, using "that," is **both correct and idiomatic**. Your sentences 3 and 4 *could be fixed* by adding a "that" in front of the word "God," like you did in your final sentence. I would say that 3 and 4 are still technically correct in their current form, without the "that," but sound awkward. Sentence 2 seems like the least preferable of all the options.

Comment: Also see https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pray+that+God+give%2Cpray+that+God+shall+give%2Cpray+that+God+may+give%2Cpray+that+God+gives&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 as compared with https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pray+God+give%2Cpray+God+shall+give%2Cpray+God+may+give%2Cpray+God+gives&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3, indicating that the **plain subjunctive** version is more common *without* the word "that," while the **indicative** or the **subjunctive with "may"** is more common *with* the word "that."

Comment: So, it appears that if you modify your Sentence 2 to, "We pray **that** God gives you health," it would then be the most preferable syntax in current usage (from looking at the timeline on the second linked Ngram).

Comment: That's a surprise to me, as I think the subjunctive version sounds better (with or without "that").

Comment: To my ear, only #3 is ungrammatical: "We pray God shall give you health."   Modal **shall** makes a definite statement about the future or expresses an obligation.  Neither is open to entreaty.

Comment: God doesn't care. God will know what you mean!  (That's the nice thing about being "all knowing")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**
2 is grammatically correct.
1 could be considered correct, idiomatically.
3 & 4 are muddled versions of different idiomatic expressions.

Here's why...

In all of these examples you have the idiomatic "we pray", which essentially means "*we will pray that...*" or "*we are praying that...*".

'God' is singular, so normally it would be correct to say "*god gives*", in the same way that we would say 'he gives' but 'they (plural) *give*'. This is why example 2 is correct from a modern grammar point of view. It could be understood as "*we are praying that God will give you health*".

However, it is also idiomatic to say "God *give* you health" in isolation. This is the *subjunctive* mood, used to express a wish. It is particularly common in religious contexts, for example "*God save the King!*". Saying "God give you health" essentially means "***May** God give you health*". So, example 1 could also be considered correct if you are saying that this subjunctive statement is what you are praying.

Example 3 is wrong. "Shall" means that something will happen for a certainty. It doesn't make sense to pray - to *ask* God - for something that surely will happen.

Example 4 isn't a correct example of the subjunctive mood - the word 'may' is in the wrong place. "God *may* give you health" could mean that he *might possibly* give you it. You could say, in isolation, "May God give you health", which would be another example of the subjunctive mood, but it doesn't make sense to say that as part of the wider statement, because saying "*I pray*" is arguably the same as saying "*may...*", as they are both ways of expressing that you hope something will happen.

Comment: I agree with you on **shall** but would disagree when you say **may** isn't right.  That which **may** happen has no prohibition or impediment to it happening.  So the prayer is a prayer that it not be impossible.

Comment: @TimR It's the precise wording of the OP's option that isn't right. "May god do [x]" is the introduction to a wish; "God may do [x]" denotes a possibility. Let's not get into a religious debate, but I don't think people pray to God and ask that he 'might possibly' do something.

Comment: I'm keeping it linguistic.  You're rejecting something that is extremely well attested.

Comment: @TimR but this is a linguistic point - you said "that which may happen". That's different to "may it happen". Very different. I've covered both for the purpose of being thorough but the OP only asked about one, which is wrong.

Comment: I bolded the word **may** there to put focus on the verb and its meaning.  To pray God **may** do something is to pray that there be no impediment to God's doing it.  (I think we can agree that the question "How can God be impeded?" is not a linguistic question but a metaphysical one. The metaphysical answer would be that the impediment would have to one that was Self-imposed, with the assumption that God has a self, which is what prayer assumes, sort of.)

Comment: @TimR Well... I know this is technically a religious point, but as God is believed to be omnipotent, there isn't any impediment to him doing anything, therefore it would be illogical (and by the same token not idiomatic either) to pray that he doesn't have any impediment.

Comment: The impediment is not anything that stands in God's way; it is standing between the petitioner and what is being prayed for. It might not be part of the Divine Plan that the petitioner enjoy safe travels, say.  But that's pulling the discussion unnecessarily into the theology sphere, when what governs this situation is how the language of petitioning and entreaty works in English.

Comment: may/let used to be called subjunctives. May God give you health. Let God give you health.